# Is a vector space automatically spacelike if it has a basis of spacelike vectors?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, causality, linear-algebra

I am studying Kerr Spacetime and I am not sure about something used in a proof I am trying to understand.

I am wondering, if you consider a 4-dimensional Lorentzian manifold $\mathcal{M}$ and $X_i \in \mathfrak{X}(\mathcal{M})$, $i=1,\dots 3$ spacelike. Consider the hypersurface $N$ where $t=t_0=const$ and suppose the vectors $X_i $ form a basis of $T_p(N)$ at each point. Does this make $T_p(N)$ (and therefore $N$) spacelike already? Because in the proof they say that the $X_i$ are also mutually orthogonal and I am not sure if this is actually needed here.

Comment: (1,0)=(1,2)+(1,-2).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, e.g. in Minkowski space we can reconstruct timelike vectors as linear combinations of spacelike vectors.

However, orthogonality of a spacelike basis is a sufficient condition to ensure that any linear combination is again spacelike.

Comment: A possibly useful necessary and sufficient condition for three vectors to span a spacelike 3-dimensional subspace of Minkowski space would be that the $3\times3$ matrix of their inner products has all its eigenvalues positive.